# Read and Write separately in python

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to create a very simple program in python that needs to read input from the user and write output accordingly. I need an output similar to this:

```
$./program.py
say something: Hello World
result: hello world
```

The thing is that i need to read input indefinitely, each time the user inputs data i would like that the printed data doesn't obstruct the input prompt. It will even better that no newlines be printed, keeping the output as above: a line for reading and another for writing.

I tried using curses but i don't want the hole screen to be used, just the two lines.

Comment: Each time a character is printed in the first line, it should be echoed in the second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
no = 0
while True:
    user_input = str(raw_input('\033[2A'*no + '\033[KSay something: '))
    print '\033[KResult: ' + user_input
    no = 1
```

This how it looks after entering the string:

[image: Working solution]

This implementation works on windows, however, if you use Linux, if I am not mistaken these are not necessary:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

EDIT: Modified my code a bit so it does not overwrite the text that was printed before the execution of the code. Also added an image of working implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do veeeery simple trick:

```
from os import system
while True:
    system('clear')  # or 'cls' if you are running windows
    user_input = input('say something:')
    print('result: ' + user_input)
    input()
```

Comment: This will clear the screen immediately after printing the result, so you will never see it

Comment: Won't this "update" the screen only after Enter key be pressed?

Comment: Sure it works, but I wonder if OP wants to update the screen on every "key got pressed event". If it's the case, it would be a little harder to do.

Comment: KISS :) Let's worry about it later. If this is not the solution OP is looking for, we will find something more complicated.

Comment: the problem is that clearing the screen is the exact opposite to what i'm looking for. I would like to clear only the used two lines.